# How to get text of image using Tesseract

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I get this cropped image from my pdf:
[image: cropped speckled image after pdf to jpeg conversion]

After preprocessing this is how I feed it to Tesseract OCR

```
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang='eng')
```

But the ocr'ed `text` is empty.

Edit:

I load the full image and crop it to this. Once it is cropped I apply sharpening filter to it and then remove salt and pepper

```
pages = convert_from_path("../data/2.pdf", fmt='JPEG',
                          poppler_path=r"D:\poppler-0.68.0\bin")

reader = easyocr.Reader(['en']) # need to run only once to load model into memory
for page in pages:

      page.save('image.jpg', 'JPEG')
      image = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
        
      img = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
      img = img[cord[2]:cord[3], cord[0]:cord[1]]
      kernel = np.array([[-1,-1,-1], [-1,9,-1], [-1,-1,-1]])
      img = cv2.filter2D(img, -1, kernel)
      img = cv2.medianBlur(img, 3)
      text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
```

This image is a part of PDF. PDF is converted to jpg and then loaded again and then this section is cropped out by giving BB coordinates.

Edit:
Using the example below this is the output after preprocessing:
[image: Preprocessed image after suggested ansnwer]

But the ocr'ed `text` output it prints is still off:

```
AQ@O FCI
```

Comment: This question is being discussed on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404771/215552) cc @GinoMempin

Comment: Your code would get you a IndentationError - so thats _not_ what you are running.

Comment: This is not really a good question for SO. Your code _works_ - its just that the OCR done by tesseract is not "up to par" to what your brain can do - big surprise. The choice of preprocessing to be done is highly input-dependent - what works for one image may or may not work for others. Diskussing things to do for preprocessing is more a tutorial then something that can/should be done here. I suggest researching preprocessing image methods - there are even older posts that do that: [tesseract ocr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28935983/preprocessing-image-for-tesseract-ocr-with-opencv)

Comment: Some other ocr quesstions that might help you out:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54940022/opencv-image-transformation-for-tesseract-ocr  , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60624019/how-to-improve-ocr-with-pytesseract-text-recognition ,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64099248/pytesseract-improve-ocr-accuracy , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480013/image-processing-to-improve-tesseract-ocr-accuracy , ... (google with:  _ocr dilatate erode improve site:stackoverflow.com_)

Comment: Edited: inlcuded speckled image back in (without this Q makes no sense) and fixed the IndentationError (ealier revisions did not have it - so probably caused by editing)

Answer (score 3):

I have a two-step solution

---

- 1. Apply Dilation followed by Erosion ([Closing](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html))
- 2. Apply thresholding.

---

Now why do we apply dilation followed by erosion?

As we can see the input image is consisting of artifacts around each character. Applying Closing operation will reduce the artifacts.

[image]

The artifacts are reduced but not completely gone. Therefore if we apply [adaptive-threshold](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html), result will be:

[image]

Now the image is suitable for reading:

```
AOF CIF
```

Code:

---

```py
import cv2
from pytesseract import image_to_string

img = cv2.imread("7UGLJ.png")
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
(h, w) = gry.shape[:2]
gry = cv2.resize(gry, (w*2, h*2))
cls = cv2.morphologyEx(gry, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, None)
thr = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(cls, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,
                            cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 41, 10)
txt = image_to_string(thr)
print(txt)
```

Comment: This question might be off topic but how does one choose specific image processing steps to apply? Is it hit and trial? or learnt through experience

Comment: Image is clearer but it prints out nothing

Comment: What is your pytesseract version? Maybe you should update

Comment: '0.3.7'  .......

Comment: Please update it to the latest version and try again

Comment: @ahx https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/  => actual version is 0.3.7 ?

Comment: @PatrickArtner I'm sorry, I was expecting an output of `print(pytesseract.get_tesseract_version())` which is 4.1.1. You are right, thanks for the warning. I'll be more careful next time.